# How to remove parameter details from pytest html report?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, pytest-html

I am using pytest.mark.parametrize for data driven testing. Now when I am generating the html report, the test case name is coming like below which includes all the parameters(data). My goal is to capture only the test case name like "test_RSA_Health" and remove all additional details from the "Test" column of the report. Is it possible?

[image]

My Code:
conftest

```
import time
import allure
import pytest
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from Utilities.filepath import *


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    test_fn = item.obj
    docstring = getattr(test_fn, '__doc__')
    if docstring:
        rep.nodeid = docstring
    return rep


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def selenium_driver(request):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    #     chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    #     chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #     chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    #     chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    s = Service("C:\\Users\\aprat\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\selenium\\chromedriver98\\chromedriver.exe")
    url = "https:test.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.set_window_size(1200, 600)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "user_name").send_keys("9998887776")
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password_name").send_keys("qwerty123")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type= 'submit']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.close()


@pytest.fixture()
def log_on_failure(request, selenium_driver):
    yield
    item = request.node
    driver = selenium_driver
    if item.rep_call.failed:
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="screenshot", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

test script:

```
import time
import pytest
from Pages.HomePage import HomePage
from TestCases.BaseTest import BaseTest
from Utilities import dataProvider


class Test_RSA_Health(BaseTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("pin,sumvalue,mobileno,selfage,fullname,email,firstname,lastname,dob,income,pan,designation,add1,add2,height,weight,nomfirstname,nomlastname,nomdob", dataProvider.get_data("rsa_health"))
    def test_RSA_Health(self,pin,sumvalue,mobileno,selfage,fullname,email,firstname,lastname,dob,income,pan,designation,add1,add2,height,weight,nomfirstname,nomlastname,nomdob):
        home = HomePage(self.driver)
        healthinsuranepage = home.SelectHealth()
        self.VerifyPresence_PinCodeTextBox()
        healthinsuranepage.landing_page()
        healthinsuranepage.InputPin(pin)
        healthinsuranepage.SelectSum(str(sumvalue))
        healthinsuranepage.InputMobileNo(mobileno)
        insureddetailspage = healthinsuranepage.ClickNext()
        self.VerifyPresence_SelfCheckBox()
        insureddetailspage.landing_page()
        insureddetailspage.SelectMemberSelf()
        self.VerifyPresence_SelfAgeTextBox()
        insureddetailspage.InputAge(selfage)
        time.sleep(2)
        quotespage = insureddetailspage.ClickNext()
        time.sleep(5)
        quotespage.landing_page()
        quotespage.ShareQuotes()
        time.sleep(3)
        quotespage.SelectAllQuotes()
        time.sleep(2)
        quotespage.ClickNext1()
        self.VerifyPresence_NameTextBox()
        quotespage.InputName(fullname)
        quotespage.InputEmail(email)
        quotespage.InputMobileNo(mobileno)
        time.sleep(2)
        quotespage.ClickSubmit()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.VerifyPresence_CloseButton()
        time.sleep(2)
        quotespage.ClickCloseButton()
        time.sleep(2)
        policydetailspage = quotespage.RSAPlanSelect()
        time.sleep(3)
        propdetailspage = policydetailspage.ConfirmTenure()
        policydetailspage.landing_page()
        self.VerifyPresence_FirstNameTextBox()
        propdetailspage.landing_page()
        propdetailspage.InputFirstName(firstname)
        propdetailspage.InputLastName(lastname)
        propdetailspage.InputDOB(dob)
        propdetailspage.SelectPropGender()
        propdetailspage.InputEmailId(email)
        propdetailspage.InputContactNo(mobileno)
        propdetailspage.InputIncome(income)
        propdetailspage.InputPANCard(pan)
        propdetailspage.SelectOccupationDropdown()
        self.VerifyPresence_SelectOccupationOption()
        propdetailspage.SelectOccupation()
        propdetailspage.InputDesignation(designation)
        propdetailspage.SelectMaritalStatusDropdown()
        self.VerifyPresence_MaritalStatusOption()
        propdetailspage.SelectMaritalStatus()
        propdetailspage.SelectEducationDropdown()
        self.VerifyPresence_QualificationOption()
        propdetailspage.SelectQualification()
        propdetailspage.SelectTPANameDropdown()
        self.VerifyPresence_TPANameOption()
        propdetailspage.SelectTPA()
        propdetailspage.InputAdd1(add1)
        propdetailspage.InputAdd2(add2)
        selfdetailspage = propdetailspage.ClickNext()
        self.VerifyPresence_SelfFirstNameTextBox()
        selfdetailspage.landing_page()
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfFirstName(firstname)
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfLastName(lastname)
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfDOB(dob)
        selfdetailspage.SelectSelfGender()
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfHeight(height)
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfWeight(weight)
        selfdetailspage.InputSelfDesignation(designation)
        selfdetailspage.InputNomineeFName(nomfirstname)
        selfdetailspage.InputNomineeLName(nomlastname)
        selfdetailspage.InputNomineeDOB(nomdob)
        selfdetailspage.SelectNomineeGender()
        selfdetailspage.SelectNomineeRltnDropdown()
        self.VerifyPresence_NomRelationOption()
        selfdetailspage.SelectNomineeRelation()
        questionariespage = selfdetailspage.ClickNext()
        time.sleep(4)
        questionariespage.landing_page()
        policyreviewpage = questionariespage.ClickNext()
        self.VerifyPresence_NameValidationText()
        policyreviewpage.landing_page()
        proposer_name = policyreviewpage.GetName()
        proposer_email = policyreviewpage.GetEmail()
        proposer_mobno = policyreviewpage.GetPhoneNo()
        try:
            assert proposer_name == fullname
            assert proposer_email == email
            assert int(proposer_mobno) == mobileno
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        policyreviewpage.FinalSubmit()
        self.VerifyPresence_ShareButton()
        policyreviewpage.SharePolicy()
```

Comment: Pass the parameters in a list or a dict and then extract them within the test. Only the list/dict name will appear.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a  bit with an example? not sure about your approach.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something else and accidentally ended up making what you want.
it is a hack that may run into some flaws but if somebody finds it useful that's great.

If your pytest-html parametrize results are displayed as multiple tests this will not combine them into a single test but it will remove the parameter from the name.

```
# conftest.py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    if "[" in report.nodeid and "]" in report.nodeid:
        end_idx = report.nodeid.index("[")
        report.nodeid = report.nodeid[:end_idx]
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
test_details = [{'pin': 444, 'sumvalue': 444,.....}]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'test_data' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("test_data", test_details)

def test_RSA_Health(self,test_data)
    pin = test_data['pin']
```

Or like this:

```
test_details = [{'pin': 444, 'sumvalue': 444,.....}]
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_data", [(test_details)]
 def test_RSA_Health(self,test_data)
        pin = test_data['pin']
```